# C# Динамическое создание объектов в дополнительном потоке

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Ситуация:

1. При запуске программы из интернета загружается XML файл с N элементов (и свойствами каждого внутри)
2. Перебором XML получаем данные, и на их основе динамически создаем N объектов
   **Panel**. При создании каждого **Panel** подгружаются дополнительные данные из интернета
3. После создания, каждый **Panel** отправляется на форму (если быть точнее - в контейнер **FlowLayoutPanel**).

Из-за этого запуск приложения (появление формы) идет 6-7 секунд, что недопустимо.

Пробовал сделать всю функцию в отдельном потоке, но компилятор ругается на то, что нельзя создавать дочерний объект в контейнере, созданном в другом потоке.

Что предпринять?

Comment: Ну, читайте данные в другом потоке, перекидывайте в главный, на их основе создавайте контролы.

Answer (score 1):

Надо воспользоваться `Invoke` методом:

```
void FillFLP(List<Panel> panels)
{
    //заполнение Вашего FlowLayoutPanels
}

void LoadData()
{
    List<Panel> panels = new List<Panel>();
    //загрузка данных в panels

    this.Invoke(new Action<List<Panel>>(FillFLP), panels);
}

//а где-нибудь в Form_Load добавляете этот код
Task task = new Task(LoadData);
task.Start();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, дома попробую и отпишусь.